# git branch -r --merged not showing merged branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to tidy up our remote repository and I have some issue.

I am trying to delete all remote branches which have been merged into anything (we had some strange workflow).

The issue is that `git branch -r --merged` shows just couple of branches, when on our BitBucket I see dozens of branches marked as merged.

The issue MAY BE related to the fact that I have run one script already:
`git branch -r --merged | egrep "(^\*|feature|bugfix|hotfix)" | sed 's/origin\///' | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin` which suppose to do that however it somehow worked - command progressed, pushed to origin but remote branches have not been deleted.

Before that it was showing proper list of branches, but now something is not working as expected.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Note : `git branch --merged` uses `HEAD` as the reference to compare branches against, so the results can vary depending on the currently checked out branch. You might have already taken that into account, just checking.

Comment: i have tried all: master, develop and nextrelease still not showing all branches

Comment: Your local branches are *yours*. Maybe they're not merged. The Bitbucket repo has its own branches. Maybe those *are* merged.